# Heroku Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

Tags: heroku, docker, apache2

I'm trying to deploy a containerized app to heroku.
MY Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-cli && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "ServerName 0.0.0.0" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /etc/apache2/envvars"]
ADD . /var/www/html   # I'm currently in my project directory

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

After pushing this to heroku by `heroku container:push web --app myapp` it gives me this message:

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

I tried `CMD ["sudo","/usr/sbin/apache2","-D","FOREGROUND"]` but nothing happened.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Not familiar with heroku, however permission denied would point to running as a user other than root. Could also be a port in use by another app.